# Get the (multiplicative) product of a tuple or list?

Tags: python, standard-library

Let's say I have a

```
class Rectangle(object):                                               
def __init__(self, length, width, height=0):                                                   
    self.l = length                                               
    self.w = width                                                
    self.h = height                                               
    if not self.h:                                                     
        self.a = self.l * self.w                                       
    else:                                                              
        from itertools import combinations                            
        args = [self.l, self.w, self.h]                                
        self.a = sum(x*y for x,y in combinations(args, 2)) * 2
                 # original code:
                 # (self.l * self.w * 2) + \                            
                 # (self.l * self.h * 2) + \                            
                 # (self.w * self.h * 2)                                
        self.v = self.l * self.w * self.h
```

What's everyone's take on line 12?

```
self.a = sum(x*y for x,y in combinations(args, 2)) * 2
```

<strike>I've heard that explicit list index references should be avoided.</strike>

<strike>Is there a function I can use that acts like `sum()`, but only for multiplication?</strike>

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since this is in the top Google results, I'll just add that since Python 3.8, you can do :

```
from math import prod
t = (5, 10)
l = [2, 100]
prod(t) # 50
prod(l) # 200
```

Comment: Even though this doesn't actually answer my question, it matches the title, and should be the easiest to find in a quick search. To be completely accurate, though, I would want to sum these product results together: `sum(map(math.prod, itertools.combinations([l, w, h], 2))) * 2`

Comment: Haha thanks for maintaining this question 9 years later! A slightly shorter version: `2*(h*w+h*l+l*w)`. `itertools.combinations` is indeed useful for higher dimensions, but `math.prod` doesn't seem to help much.

Answer (score 11):

I don't see any problem with using indexes here:

```
sum([x[0] * x[1] for x in combinations(args, 2)])
```

If you really want to avoid them, you can do:

```
sum([x*y for x,y in combinations(args, 2)])
```

But, to be honest I would prefer your commented out version. It is clear, readable and more explicit. And you don't really gain much by writing it as above just for three variables.

> Is there a function I can use that acts like sum(), but only for
>   multiplication?

Built-in? No. But you can get that functionality rather simply with the following:

```
In : a=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

In : from operator import mul

In : reduce(mul,a)
Out: 720
```

Comment: reduce does not exist any more from python 3.0+

Comment: +1 and answer for the `reduce(mul, l)` tip. I agree, the first draft was clearer, I was just looking for a one liner to expand my list comprehension...comprehension. `:D`

Comment: @Serdalis: Correct, thanks for the tip. But there is `functools.reduce`, which is same actually.

Answer (score 6):

In short, just use `np.prod`

```
import numpy as np
my_tuple = (2, 3, 10)
print(np.prod(my_tuple))  # 60
```

Which is in your use case

```
np.sum(np.prod(x) for x in combinations(args, 2))
```

`np.prod` can take both lists and tuple as a parameter. It returns the product you want.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
from operator import mul
sum(reduce(mul,combinations(args, 2)))
```

but I think it just makes things less readable.

However, before summing you are actually building the list of multiplication `sum([...])`.

```
self.a = sum([(x[0] * x[1] * 2) for x in combinations(args, 2)])
```

This is not needed, simply do:

```
self.a = sum(x * y * 2 for x,y in combinations(args, 2))
```

Comment: I see too many left brackets in both of your examples. I ran my code in 2.6, it compiled for me. I'll try the `for x, y in` bit, though.

Comment: I fixed my typo, you should fix yours :) there is problem here `sum(([x[0]...`

Comment: Why doesn't SO come with an interpreter for noobs like me? Good eye.

Comment: @Ugo: `(x[0] * x[1] * 2)` is not a tuple. It is same as `x[0] * x[1] * 2`. You need to put `,` in order to make a tuple of length one, e.g. `(2,)`.

Answer (score 0):

I did make a very simple definition of product; helpful for "calculating the product of a tuple"

```
def product(tuple1):
    """Calculates the product of a tuple"""
    prod = 1
    for x in tuple1:
        prod = prod * x
    return prod
```

Might be a more elegant way to do it but this seems to work OK. Presumably it would work on a list just as well.